# Редактирование SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Здравствуйте!

Имеется ли возможность редактирования чужих SharedPreferences? Собственно интересуют любые варианты.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае, чтобы получить экземпляр SharedPreferences необходим контекст активности, который недоступен извне. Поэтому если приложение не предоставляет активности, путем которой можно редактировать настройки, то таковой возможности в процессе обычной работы приложений нет. На телефоне, к которому даны права рута, можно найти настройки (это просто xml-файл) и отредактировать их вручную.

Файл настроек по умолчанию лежит здесь (имя может отличаться):

```
/data/data/com.some.package/shared_prefs/com.some.package_preferences.xml
```

Это можно проверить из консоли

```
adb shell ls /data/data/com.some.package/shared_prefs/
```

Comment: А можно подробнее, где они валяются?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! С Новым годом!

Comment: В дополнение: на самсунгах путь немного другой: 
    
    /dbdata/databases/package/shared_prefs/